# Show the stabilizer is an open subgroup

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-representations

Let $V$ be a $l-$adic representation of a Galois group $G$ where $V$ is equipped with the $l-$adic topology. Let $T_0$ be a lattice in $V$ and $H=\{g \in G \mid g(T_0)=T_0\}$. Show $H$ is an open subgroup of $G$. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: You certainly will have to assume that the action of $G$ on $V$ is *continuous* (with respect to the given topology). So you should make sure you understand what that means.

Comment: @Mathmo123 I see $T_0$ is open and we can show there’s some open subgroup contained in $H$ and we can use continuity to construct continuous map from $G$ to $V$. But I can’t find such a map.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $v_1,\dots,v_n$ be a $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$-basis for $T_0$.
Considering the map $G\to V^n$ given by $g\mapsto (gv_1,\dots,gv_n)$, we see that $U=\{g\in G\mid g(T_0)\subset T_0\}$ is an open subset of $G$.
Since $g(T_0)=T_0$ holds if and only if both $g(T_0)\subset T_0$ and $g^{-1}(T_0)\subset T_0$ holds, we get that
$$
\{g\in G\mid g(T_0)=T_0\}=U\cap U^{-1}
$$
is also open.